# Comparing values with javaScript then redirect to another url if true

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

*edit*- the problem was in the redirection and Solved by Ahmed with the immediately invoked Function Expression aka IIFE

problem redirecting to another page, values are a string and the integer "CharFields" .. else statement works fine but the if statement when I type it correct the page just refreshes and nothing happens.

I made java function to get variables from a user input trcode 
and made Django print the model in an input value those two works fine I tested them with printing,, the problem is in comparing the values and redirecting to the another URL

```js
function readText () {
    var value1 = document.getElementById("trcode").value;
    var value2 = document.getElementById("trfcode").value;
    if (value1 === value2) {
        location.href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/myposts";}
    else {
            alert("You typed: " + "Wrong Password");}
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return readText();">
<tr><td height="18" class="subheaderboldtext"> Enter Code: 
<input id="trcode" maxlength="8" class="box">
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">

<button id="trfcode" value="{{ user.profile.trf_code }}">z</button>
```

Comment: change location.href to window.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/myposts" The rest looks fine. But just to check, also add in a console.log inside the conditions. You could also do a console.log of the values before the condition to make sure you are getting the value you think you are.

Comment: still the same problem just refreshing the page !! ,, my brain is gonna explode .. searched every where for a reason ! ,, i checked the values it works fine

Comment: Can you access http://127.0.0.1:8000/myposts directly? And try this: location.href="http://google.com"; let me know if it redirects you to google.com

Comment: i added==> alert("You typed: " + "Right Password!!"); in the if statement after the location command it showed up and still no redirect !

Comment: yes i can access it and tried the google url ,, still refreshing the page :/

Comment: Just put an alert with a value in your first `if` and test it again. And for the time being comment your line `location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/myposts";` as its responsible for refreshing your page.

Comment: i already did that ahmed and it worked ! ,, the problem is in the redirection ,, have no idea why !! .. google doesn't work too !! location.href="google.com";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes to your code. The button with id `trfcode` is being assigned a value already called `user.profile.trf_code`. If you replace it with the value you are trying to match it will work fine. For testing purposes I have changed your code a bit and have assigned it a value of `z`. Upon typing `z` in input and clicking submit gives me a +ve result.

I am guessing your main concern is reading the value of user-profile `user.profile.trf_code`. So you may wanna debug this and find out if you are getting a proper value back which you are expecting.

Few tips for debugging. When you are in such a situation, please first look at the values of each element and find out even if you are getting the values back. Then next step to find out if you are getting the same values or not and so on.

Putting `value="z"` makes this working. Please note that I have added extra logs and an alert. Please feel free to remove it.

**EDIT**:

If you see in the form, I have added a function wrapping your function. This is called **immediately invoked Function Expression aka IIFE** which basically is a function and can be called right there. Form creates an event, that event has a method called `preventDefaults()` which prevents the page from reloading or refreshing upon everytime you submit. I have wrapped your method under an IIFE to prevent the page from refreshing and then called your function. I would highly recommend you adding this as a part of your question though.

Your form,

```
    <form onsubmit="return (function(event) { event.preventDefault();  readText()}) (event)">
        <tr>
            <td height="18" class="subheaderboldtext"> Enter Code:
                <input id="trcode" maxlength="8" class="box">
                <input class="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">

                <!-- <img src="/static/guest/images/querybutton.png" alt="Query Button" /> -->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
    <button id="trfcode" value="z">z</button>
```

Javascript given below,

```
function readText() {
    var value1 = document.getElementById("trcode").value;
    var value2 = document.getElementById("trfcode").value;
    console.log(`value1 = ${value1}`);
    console.log(`value2 = ${value2}`);

    if (value1 === value2) {
        // location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/myposts";
        console.log(`I am good`);
        alert(`You typed: ${value1}`);
    } else {
        console.log(`I am in else`);
        alert("You typed: " + "Wrong Password");
    }
}
```

Comment: thx ahmed for your reply but the main reason i'm doing this is to get the variable from user.profile.trf_code ,, and i have tested the values they work fine when i put a alert correct password in the if statement it works ... my problem is in the redirecting the page just refreshes !!

Comment: Your question states something different. To do that you need to call `e.preventDefault()`. Give me a second, let me provide you with an example.

Comment: i added alert with right password instead of redirecting the url and it worked .. waiting for your e.preventDefault() example to try ..

Comment: Please check the explanation and mark this as a correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: i checked the e.preventDefault() tag it's used to cancel the event if it's cancelable ,, my problem here is the opposite the event i want to happen is being canceled with no reason!! have no idea how to fix it and can't find any one who knows .. thx alot any way..  edit: have just seen your edit will try it ,, thx alot

Comment: I honestly didnt get what you are asking. If its something different than what you asked, then perhaps you should create a new question. Try asking a clear and concise question. Thank you.

Comment: sorry for that ,, first time to ask :) ,, thx alooooot your edit worked !! <3 <3 love u man xD